# Why is my GitHub pull request showing commits that aren't by me?

Tags: git, github

I am confused about why a GitHub pull request is showing lots of commits that I didn't make, when I have rebased directly off current master.

I did the following:

```
git pull 
git checkout -b my-new-branch
```

Days pass while I work on stuff, then:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'Add my amazing commit'
```

Add a few more commits, then get ready to push:

```
git fetch
git rebase master
```

The rebase runs with no conflicts, so:

```
git push origin my-new-branch
```

However, when I open the branch on GitHub, it is showing my commits on top of 92 commits from other members of my team. Why is it showing these as different to master, when I have rebased off master?

Comment: Ah, I'm wondering if it's because I rebased off local master, but hadn't yet run `git pull` on local master? If so, how can I fix this?

Comment: Git fetch doesn't update your local master. If you only do git fetch, do a rebase on origin/master instead of master.

Answer (score 4):

OK, it was because I hadn't updated my local master, because I'd only fetched and not pulled. Doh!

I fixed this as follows. First I updated the local master:

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

Then I created a *new* branch off my up-to-date copy of master:

```
git checkout -b my-second-branch
```

Then I checked what the hashes of the commits I cared about on the old branch were:

```
git whatchanged my-new-branch
```

Then I cherry-picked in the commits I cared about off the first branch, onto the second branch:

```
git cherry-pick hashofmyfirstcommit
git cherry-pick hashofmysecondcommit
```

And then I pushed the new branch:

```
git push origin my-second-branch
```

And then I created a PR off that, and deleted the old branch and the old PR.

Comment: This answer seems like a workaround that gets you where you want to go (a clean PR), but it involves a lot of extra work and won't prevent the problem from happening in the future. :(